# Como pesquisar se um array de strings contem em outro array de strings. Usando palavras completas e incompletas

Tags: flutter, dart

Como fazer para procurar em um array de strings usando palavas completas e incompletas idependente da ordem, semelhante ao que a agenda do celular faz.

Exemplo:

```
List array1 = ['Escola','Estadual','José','da','silva'];
Lista busca = ['José','Silva','Estad'];
```

Quero que buca contenha em array1, fazendo pesquisa por palavram completas e incompletas.

Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
void main() {
  List storeName = ['ESCOLA','ESTADUAL','SAO','JOAO'];
  List queryList = ['ESCOLA','SAO', 'JOAO'];

  List vazia = [];

  for(var i = 0; i< storeName.length;i++){
    for(var x = 0; x< queryList.length;x++){
      if(storeName[i].contains(queryList[x])){
       if(vazia.indexOf(storeName[i]) == -1){
         vazia.add(storeName[i]);
       }else{
         print('n tem');
       }
      }
    }
  }
  print(vazia);
}
```

Mas o que eu realmente quero é que se eu fizer:

```
List array1 = ['Escola','Estadual','José','da','silva'];
Lista busca = ['José','Silva','Esta'];

busca in array1 = true
```

E se pesquisar assim, seja false:

```
List array1 = ['Escola','Estadual','José','da','silva'];
Lista busca = ['José','Silva','Estlp'];

busca in array1 = false
```

Outro exemplo interessante é:

```
.contains("Dart is nice", "nice Dart")); //true
.contains("Dart is nice", "nice Darte")); //false
.contains("Dart is nice", "is Dar")); //true
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e nos informe o que já tentou até agora, assim podemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: É importante que mostre o esforço que já fez nas suas pesquisas e tentativas. Colocar um código de exemplo que está quase funcionando é uma forma de ajudar a sanar seu problema mais pontualmente. Quando colocar nos padrões para a pergunta voltar a aceitar respostas eu posto uma das possíveis soluções para seu caso. Se tiver o exemplo utilizo até mesmo seu exemplo e apenas ajusto com o que necessitar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você vai possuir duas listas de palavras, você deve utilizar um `loop` para comparar seus registros, dessa forma:

```
void main() {
  List<String> array1 = ['Escola','Estadual','José','da','silva'];
  List<String> busca = ['José','Silva','Esta'];

  bool exists = false;

  List<String> array1Lower = array1.map((item) => item.toLowerCase()).toList();

  for(String textoBusca in busca){     
    for(String value in array1Lower){     
      exists = value.contains(textoBusca.toLowerCase());
      if (exists)
        break;
    }

    if (!exists)
       break;
  }

  print(exists);
}
```

**Explicação**

Como você quer que funcione como uma busca genérica *caseInsensitive*, é necessário converter todas as palavras de ambas as listas para *LowerCase*, caso o contrário o Dart irá entender como palavras distintas.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 2):

Uma das possíveis implementações:

```dart
void main() { 
  // Exemplo 1
  List array1 = ['Escola','Estadual','José','da','silva'];
  List buscas = ['José','Silva','Estad'];

  bool achouExemplo1 = pesquisar(array1, buscas);
  print("Exemplo 1: $achouExemplo1");


  // Exemplo 2
  String frase = "Dart is nice";
  String fraseBusca = "is dar";

  List array2 = frase.split(" ");  
  List buscas2 = fraseBusca.split(" ");

  bool achouExemplo2 = pesquisar(array2, buscas2, caseSensitive: false);
  print("Exemplo 2: $achouExemplo2");  
}


// função responsável por processar a busca nos arrays.
bool pesquisar(palavras, buscas, {caseSensitive = false}){  
  bool match = false;

  for(String busca in buscas){
    busca = caseSensitive ? busca : busca.toUpperCase();

    for(String palavra in palavras){
      String auxPalavra = caseSensitive ? palavra : palavra.toUpperCase();
      match = auxPalavra.contains(busca);

      if(match) break;      
    }

    if(!match) break;
  }

  return match;
}
```

A função `pesquisar()` tem a opção de fazer a busca considerando ou não o `case sensitive`. O parâmetro é opcional e caso não seja informada assume como `false`. Utilizei um exemplo de cada no código proposto. No exemplo 2 está utilizando o parâmetro `case sensitive` na chamada.

O código pode ser testado no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/).

Comment: Isso funcionou perfeitamente, estou usando ate hoje. Desculpa pela demora no feedback